# Cannot convert ComparisonResult to closure result type Bool

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:

```
var data = [list]()
var filtered = [list]()

struct list {
    var label1 : String = ""
    var label2 : String = ""
    var label3 : String = ""
}


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = data.filter { $0.label1.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(searchText) }
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }


    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I add to list from sql query results and they appear fine but when i try to implement a search feature i can't build it with an error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'ComparisonResult' to closure result
>   type 'Bool'

Comment: you can do this way data.filter { $0.label1.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(searchText) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note, that the [`filter(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893557-filter) accept the closure, that should return the `Bool` value:

```
func filter(_ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Element]
```

According to this, try to look at result of `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`. It returns the [`ComparisonResult`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/comparisonresult), not `Bool`. So, you should compare it to something of `ComparisonResult` type (i.e. `.orderedAscending.`, `.orderedSame` or `.orderedDescending`).

Example:

```
let filtered = data.filter {
    $0.label1.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(searchText) == .orderedAscending 
}
```

UPD.

`localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` is really about `sort`ing. If you want to filter your data by some query and case is doesn't matter, i suggest you do `.lowercased()` on both `data.label1` and `searchText`:

```
let filtered = data.filter {
    $0.label1.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) == .orderedAscending 
}
```

Comment: i could build without error this time but searching does not filters, it's always unfiltered data

Comment: i had to remove == .orderedAscending but it did work. Thank you